# Where can I find jsdom documentation?

Tags: node.js, jsdom

I'm looking for documentation on jsdom that is more descriptive than just the readme at https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom.

Specifically, I'm looking for instructions on how to interpret the nodeType property of a DOM node created by jsdom. The property stores an integer which has no inherent meaning as far as I can see. In the immediate example I'm sure there's some testing I can do to discover what integer maps to what DOM node type, but it's taking a long time to write custom tests and introspection code just to work my way around these objects. Other questions that I'd use the doc for are about how to access a node's parent directly, traverse children, access text data, etc. (all by accessing object properties directly outside of any jquery specific functions).

Where can I find jsdom documentation on the properties of a DOM node?

Comment: @casperOne, can you elaborate on why this was closed? AFAIK none of my other documentation-request style questions I've asked were closed like this. They haven't caused debate/arguments/polling etc. Should I have included the full list google searches / unhelpful resources I had already tried to show all the research that had gone into the quesiton before posting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not specific to jsdom, the NodeTypes - Named Constants table at http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp seems to relate to the values I'm seeing for nodeType values.

Comment: And regarding the other questions I mentioned, http://www.w3schools.com/dom/default.asp seems to answer them all. No detailed doc = jsdom just uses common conventions I just wanted aware of